# Animations running at the same time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I made a unity program in C# in which the player can move and jump.

When I run the code the player's `idle animation` and the player's `jumping animation` both play at the same time in the animator causing a glitch and it doesn't look that good.

Here's the code which I used:

```
if (Input.GetKey("d") || Input.GetKey("right")) 
{
    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(Forwardspeed, 0f);
    animator.Play("Player_run");
    spr.flipX = false;
}
else if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("left"))
{
    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(-Forwardspeed, 0f);
    animator.Play("Player_run");
    spr.flipX = true;
}
else if (!Input.anyKeyDown)
{
    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    animator.Play("Player_idle");
}
else if (Input.GetKey("space"))
{
    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(Forwardspeed, Uppwardforce);
    animator.Play("Player_jump");
}
```

Comment: so when you run and want to jump you have a problem, because you activate idle?

Answer (score 1):

Based around your code design, why not use the idle as an else condition? This way if you don't have a key down, your player will just idle. 
eg:

```
    if (Input.GetKey("d") || Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(Forwardspeed, 0f);
        animator.Play("Player_run");
        spr.flipX = false;
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(-Forwardspeed, 0f);
        animator.Play("Player_run");
        spr.flipX = true;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(Forwardspeed, Uppwardforce);
        animator.Play("Player_jump");
    }
   else
    {
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        animator.Play("Player_idle");
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

why dont do that:

```
else if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("left"))
{
    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(-Forwardspeed, 0f);
    animator.Play("Player_run");
    spr.flipX = true;
    if (Input.GetKey("space"))
    {
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(Forwardspeed, Uppwardforce);
        animator.Play("Player_jump");
    }

}
```

if you dont need to add force you could just test the KeyDown

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
{
    rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(Forwardspeed, Uppwardforce);
    animator.Play("Player_jump");
}
```

You hold the key "run" down and you just pulse the key space